# Spring Boot Test is not loading classes with @Component annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, orika

In my Spring Boot Application, I am writing integration tests using @SpringBootTest. I am using a config class for Configuration and used @ComponentScan on it but it's not loading components and tests are failing.

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.inventory" })
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MapperFactory mapperFactory() {
        return new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
    }
}
```

Here DefaultMapperFactory is the part of Orika Mapper which I use to convert model to DTO and vice-versa.

**ProductSupplierIntegrationTests.java**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ProductSupplierIntegrationTests {
    // tests
}
```

**Product Supplier Model**

```
@Entity
public class ProductSupplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long supplierId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Supplier supplier;

    private Double buyPrice;

    private boolean defaultSupplier;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Supplier Model**

```
@Entity
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**ProductSupplierDTO**

```
public class ProductSupplierDTO {

    private Long supplierId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    private Double buyPrice;

    private Boolean defaultSupplier;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Orika Mapper Configuration**

```
package com.example.inventory.mapper;

@Component
public class ProductSupplierMapper implements OrikaMapperFactoryConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(MapperFactory orikaMapperFactory) {
        orikaMapperFactory.classMap(ProductSupplier.class, ProductSupplierDTO.class).exclude("id")
                .field("supplier.firstName", "firstName").field("supplier.lastName", "lastName")
                .field("supplier.email", "email").byDefault().register();
    }

}
```

When I run Application, spring loads mapper and register it in contexts an converts between pojo as I specified but When I run Integration test, the mapper is not loaded and pojos are converted with default orika configuration and the fields firstName, lastName & email are not mapped in DTO.

Can anyone tell what am I missing in test configuration ?

Comment: Have you tried without dot in the field. I mean there is no need use suplier. simply use field names.

Comment: dot is used to map two class's properties in one class. I don't think that orika is the issue here as it works perfectly when I run Main Applicaton.

Comment: Your `@SpringBootTest` should reference the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: Is that @ComponentScan annotation correct - are your classes really in  "com.example.inventory"?

Comment: If I use `@SpringBootApplication` then it loads application context for each test.

Comment: Yes `@ComponentScan` annotation is correct and my class is in `com.example.inventory.mapper` package.

Comment: Is `ApplicationConfig` specific to your test or not? If we want to load a specific configuration, we can use the classes attribute of `@SpringBootTest`, otherwise it will attempt to load `@Configuration` from any inner-classes, and if that fails, it will search for your primary `@SpringBootApplication` class.

Comment: I just created Application class with `@SpringBootApplication` in Test Package and used `@ComponentScan` there. it's working perfect now. Thanks